# Iteration vs order_by() efficiency

Tags: python, sql, django, performance

I'm trying to find the highest cost item from a queryset, and I'm just wondering which of the following (if either) is more efficient

```
items = Item.objects.all()

highest_cost = max(item.cost for item in items)
#Or
highest_cost = items.order_by('-cost')[0].cost
```

I'm not super concerned about performance, I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: I believe this falls down to the ammount of entries in your db etc, you can always test and check timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can simply use django's `Max` [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
items = Item.objects.all()
items.aggregate(Max('cost'))
```

Secondly, the answer to your question depends on various factors. E.g. if the table is very big (many records, or particularly big records), you would need to avoid retrieving all of them while only needing one (first query). However, if you have millions of records in the table, and no index on the column you order by, sorting can be very slow (O(nlogn)), while finding the max is O(n).

In most cases, however, letting the DB server do the job (in your example, using `order by`) should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

order_by is much faster, especially if you have many entries in the database.